Manhwa where the villainess female lead kills her brother to become Empress, but is killed and sent back in time
I read this manhwa online. It wasn't too long ago and I think it is still on-going. Can't remember too much except some plot points.
The female lead is a princess who was manipulated into growing up not trusting her brother and eventually killing him to become the Empress (or Queen). After she kills him, she is used as a puppet and eventually dies, but ends up going to the past. As she goes through life again, she realizes her brother loved her and let her kill him. So now she is trying to help him survive against whoever manipulated her in her previous life.

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

The Tyrant Wants to be Good includes fratricide and time travel, but I don't see any indication of puppetry and his love seems obvious. I only checked the first two chapters.
